# SHA-256 paypal opencart

Tags: paypal, opencart

i have a simple question for you.
I have many sites with opencart 1.5.6.

With the new updates ( https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/ ), the module "paypal standard", integrated in opencart, it will continue to work?

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this only applies to very old operating systems.  If you are running a fairly recent server, this shouldn't be an issue.

A complete list of supported systems can be found here:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility